# Python List - set every n-th value None

Tags: python, pandas, list

As the title says, i want to know how to set every n-th value in a python list as Null. I looked after a solution in a lot of forums but i didn't find much.
I also don't want to overwrite existing values as None, instead i want to create new spaces with the value None

The list contains the date (12 dates = 1 year) and every 13th value should be empty because that row will be the average so i don't need a date

Here is my code how i generated the dates with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

numdays = 370       #i have 370 values, every day = 1 month. Starting from 1990 till June 2019
date1 = '1990-01-01'
date2 = '2019-06-01'
mydates = pd.date_range(date1, date2,).tolist()

date_all = pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='1BMS')
date_lst = [date_all]
```

The expected Output:

```
01.01.1990
01.02.1990
01.03.1990
01.04.1990
01.05.1990
01.06.1990
01.07.1990
01.08.1990
01.09.1990
01.10.1990
01.11.1990
01.12.1990
None
01.01.1991
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
numdays = 370
date1 = '1990-01-01'
date2 = '2019-06-01'
mydates = pd.date_range(date1, date2,).tolist()
date_all = pd.date_range(start=date1, end=date2, freq='1BMS')
date_lst = [date_all]

for i in range(12,len(mydates),13): # add this
    mydates.insert(i, None)
```

Comment: Maybe it was the comment breaking the code. Try again, because I personally tested it and works fine. Also the solution of @ArnoMaeck replaces the 12th element, does not insert a new one.

Comment: It doesn't accept none as a value. This is what i get when i execute:  TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'

Comment: How is that possible? I run the exact code above and see in the debugger a None value every 13th element. Can you post exactly what you ran?

Comment: I played a bit with it and now it works. Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I saw some of the answers above, but there's a way of doing this without having to loop over the complete list:

```
date_lst[12::12] = [None] * len(date_lst[12::12])
```

The first 12 in [12::12] means that the first item that should be changed is item number 12. The second 12 means that from then on every 12th item should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

## You add a step in `iloc` and set values this way.

lets generate some dummy data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Vals' : 
            pd.date_range('01-01-19','02-02-19',freq='D')})
print(df)


    Vals
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
2   2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04
4   2019-01-05
5   2019-01-06
6   2019-01-07
7   2019-01-08
```

now, you can decide your `step`

```
step = 5
new_df = df.iloc[step::step]
print(new_df)
    Vals
5   2019-01-06
10  2019-01-11
15  2019-01-16
20  2019-01-21
25  2019-01-26
30  2019-01-31
```

now, if you want to write a value to a specific column then -

```
df['Vals'].iloc[step::step] = pd.NaT
print(df)
    Vals
0   2019-01-01
1   2019-01-02
2   2019-01-03
3   2019-01-04
4   2019-01-05
5   NaT
```

Comment: But it's overwriting the 13th value, not generating a new value between the 12th and 13th

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of setting null if  the element of the list is in the 3rd position, you can make this 13th position by changed ((index+1)%13 == 0)

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
data = [None if ((index+1)%3 == 0) else d for index, d in enumerate(data)]
print(data)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, None, 4, 5, None, 7, 8, None]
```

According to your code try this:

```
date_lst = list(date_all)
dateWithNone = [None if ((index+1)%13 == 0) else d for index, d in enumerate(date_lst)]
print(dateWithNone)
```